# Is there a number field with + and - feature?

Tags: 7, entities

I am working with Form API to create a customized form shown in a block. Most of the fields are [textfield](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#textfield)s.

I need a +/- feature for a numeric textfield, i.e.:

[image]

Is there an existing field like the above I can use?

Comment: As an alternative, why not use a standard html5 number field instead? That already has an up/down button spinner provided by the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Stepper Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_stepper) module

> The Stepper Field module is based in a plugin for jQuery UI called jQuery.ui.Spinner and provides a new steps widget that can be added to any Integer field.

Here is the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is [SpinInt](https://www.drupal.org/project/spinint) module for this

> Spinint provides a simple up down arrow widget for integer number fields.